# Does a good wrapper class and/or library for open xml Excel editing exist?

Tags: excel, webserver, openxml, openxml-sdk, windows-server

I'm looking for a nice library for editing and/or generating Excel documents on our Windows server.  I feel that the open xml sdk is probably the way to go, but to me the learning curve seems steep and our dev time is limited.  I think that it just shouldn't be that difficult to edit an Excel document.  I'm ready to reinvent the wheel, but thought it would be worthwhile to ask first whether there is a good project/library out there that wraps open xml and makes interacting with Excel easier.

In this official MS tutorial, the code that retrieves the value of a cell is dozens of lines long.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739834.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#ManipulateOpenXMLExcelPowerPoint_RetrievetheValueofaCellinaWorksheet

That seems incredibly unwieldy, and I'm hoping for a better interface to this functionality.

Note: I've puzzled about how to make this question more StackOverflow friendly, but I don't know of a better way.

Comment: Are you primarily looking to edit an Excel document (change the value of a few cells) or output some data (a DB table maybe) as an Excel document?

Comment: http://closedxml.codeplex.com/ is one such wrapper.

Comment: Flowerking - I downloaded ClosedXML, worked through some examples, and it looks exactly like what I was looking for.  Exactly.  If you'd post that as an answer, I'll gladly mark it answered.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the comments mentioned a wrapper library that is exactly what I've been looking for.  [closedxml.codeplex.com](http://closedxml.codeplex.com)

Comment: I'd be wary, we've encountered memory leaks using this library.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SpreadsheetLight](http://spreadsheetlight.com/). Disclaimer: I wrote SpreadsheetLight.

And this question is possibly a duplicate of this:
[OpenXML libraries (alternatives to ClosedXML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501528/openxml-libraries-alternatives-to-closedxml)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Simple OOXML](http://simpleooxml.codeplex.com/) and it's quite neat. And free.