# Error while exporting datatable to Excel

Tags: c#

I am using below code to export excel using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. [Ms office 2003].
I need to export around 150000 rows can have maximum 300 columns.

but getting error on Get_Range. [ Working fine for 50000 rows and 40 columns]

```
public static void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt, string outputPath)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the Excel Application object
            ApplicationClass excelApp = new ApplicationClass();

            // Create a new Excel Workbook
            Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

            int sheetIndex = 0;

            // Copy each DataTable


            // Copy the DataTable to an object array
            object[,] rawData = new object[dt.Rows.Count + 1, dt.Columns.Count];

            // Copy the column names to the first row of the object array
            for (int col = 0; col < dt.Columns.Count; col++)
            {
                rawData[0, col] = dt.Columns[col].ColumnName;
            }

            // Copy the values to the object array
            for (int col = 0; col < dt.Columns.Count; col++)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < dt.Rows.Count; row++)
                {
                    rawData[row + 1, col] = dt.Rows[row].ItemArray[col];
                }
            }

            // Calculate the final column letter
            string finalColLetter = string.Empty;
            string colCharset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            int colCharsetLen = colCharset.Length;

            if (dt.Columns.Count > colCharsetLen)
            {
                finalColLetter = colCharset.Substring(
                    (dt.Columns.Count - 1) / colCharsetLen - 1, 1);
            }

            finalColLetter += colCharset.Substring(
                    (dt.Columns.Count - 1) % colCharsetLen, 1);

            // Create a new Sheet
            Worksheet excelSheet = (Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets.Add(
                excelWorkbook.Sheets.get_Item(++sheetIndex),
                Type.Missing, 1, XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);

            excelSheet.Name = "data";

            // Fast data export to Excel
            string excelRange = string.Format("A1:{0}{1}",
                finalColLetter, dt.Rows.Count + 1);

           //excelSheet.get_Range(
            excelSheet.get_Range(excelRange, Type.Missing).Value2 = rawData;

            // Mark the first row as BOLD
            ((Range)excelSheet.Rows[1, Type.Missing]).Font.Bold = true;


            // Save and Close the Workbook
            excelWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\\Dashsrv\\data.Xls", XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            excelWorkbook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            excelWorkbook = null;

            // Release the Application object
            excelApp.Quit();
            excelApp = null;

            // Collect the unreferenced objects
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            MessageBox.Show("File created at");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Getting error on below line of code

> [{"Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"}]
>   excelSheet.get_Range(excelRange, Type.Missing).Value2 = rawData;

IS `Get_Range()` has some limitation for rows/Columns?

As I know for MS Office 2003 column's limit is 256, not sure about rows limt.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen my code-sample here?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63546720/how-to-export-a-datatable-into-an-excel-file-via-powershell

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2003 can have a maximum of 65536 rows in a single worksheet ([specification](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx))

Excel 2007 and newer can have 1048576 rows (specification: [Excel 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx), [Excel 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx) and [Excel 2013](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HA103980614.aspx))

Comment: Could you please suggest any other way to export the excel in fast way. as compare to above?

Comment: Try OfficeOpenXML instead of Interop. - http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20an%20Excel%20spreadsheet%20from%20scratch&referringTitle=Home

Comment: If it is just the data you want to export, you might get through with simple CSV. If there are formulas etc., then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501528/openxml-libraries-alternatives-to-closedxml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529366/does-a-good-wrapper-class-and-or-library-for-open-xml-excel-editing-exist

Comment: Thanks for reply.

In above code can we directly open excel document without saving it.
above code is really working good with MS OFFICE 2010 [No Error as can insert 1048576  rows].

waiting for response.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2003 row limit is 65,536 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/120596

Comment: above code is compatible with MS OFFICE 2003, 
Is any DLL or SDK that can I install on my system to create Excel that can be open with 2007 and higher version of MS Office.

I had install FilFormatCoverter 

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924074

but need some dll that can be add in my C# app so that in above code 
in 
 excelWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\\Dashsrv\\data.Xls", XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, , , , , , , , , ,);

I can set XlFileFormat to xlOpenXMLWorkbook.