# SDK for MS OFFICE 2010 Excel

Tags: c#

I have MS OFFICE 2003 Installed at my system and I am creating a .XLS file through code using Microsoft.office.interop which is compatible with 2003 files only.

I want to create .Xlsx file compatible with 2007 and  higher versions.
can there is some SDK that can be install with 2003 and make excel comaptible with higher versions of MS OFFICE.

Can refer below link for more clarity [the code which I am using for excel export is in below link]

[Error while exporting datatable to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459476/error-while-exporting-datatable-to-excel)

Comment: Search engines exist for this. Sorry, I don't want to be rude, but asking for recommendations is frowned here

Comment: Thanks for suggestion,

But I had tried at my end , only then post my problem here. For hopping to some solution for my problem.

Comment: Someone has pointed you in the right (FREE) direction.

Comment: The answer is no. Excel 2003 doesn't have any support internally for future versions of Excel it doesn't know exist. If you want support for a newer Excel version, you need to either upgrade your Excel version to the new one you want to use features from, or buy a commercial product that adds that functionality. (And this is common sense: "I have a 1999 Ford F150. Can I just plug in/screw on parts from a 2013 F150 to add anti-lock brakes, computerized fuel injection, and get a new car warranty?" Of course not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/.net/excel-component.aspx), but it's paid.
And you could check [Epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). As far as i know, it's free.