# How to export a DataTable into an Excel file via Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell, datatable

I was searching for a simple and fast option to export an existing DataTable-object via Powershell into an Excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I came up with this code. I hope it helps others with same challenge:

```
# get XML-schema and XML-data from the table: 
$schema = [System.IO.StringWriter]::new()
$myTable.WriteXmlSchema($schema)
$data = [System.IO.StringWriter]::new()
$myTable.WriteXml($data)

# start Excel and prepare some objects:
$xls = New-Object -Comobject Excel.Application
$xls.DisplayAlerts = $false
$xls.Visible = $false
$book = $xls.Workbooks.Add()
$sheet = $book.Worksheets[1]
$range = $sheet.Range("A1")

# import the data and save the file:
$map = $book.XmlMaps.Add($schema)
[void]$book.XmlImportXml($data, $map, $true, $range)
$book.SaveAs("c:\temp\test.xlsx", 51)
$xls.Quit()
```

Comment: Have you heard about the Powershell module [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel). That would make your life much easier I think and it does not need an installed Excel. That comes in handy when you want to run some task on a server wtihout an installed office.  ;-)